# Magento2: Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: magento2, index

We use mageplaza extension products grid. Impossible open products --> catalog

```
Notice: Undefined index: position in /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/Mageplaza/ProductGrid/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Thumbnail.php on line 183
```

on line 183 code:

```
/**
 * @param Product $product
 *
 * @return string
 * @throws LocalizedException
 */
public function prepareFileData($product)
{
    $data     = [];
    $position = [];
    $images   = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $image->setFileSize($this->_helperData->fileSizeFormat($this->_file->getFileSize($image->getPath())));
        $data[$image->getValueId()] = $image->getData();
    }
    $imageEntities = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
    foreach ($imageEntities as $imageEntity) {
        $data[$imageEntity->getId()]['types'] = [
            'image'        => 0,
            'small_image'  => 0,
            'thumbnail'    => 0,
            'swatch_image' => 0,
        ];
        foreach ($imageEntity->getTypes() as $type) {
            $data[$imageEntity->getId()]['types'][$type] = 1;
        }
    }
    foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
        $position[$key] = $item['position'];
    }
    array_multisort($position, SORT_ASC, $data);

    return HelperData::jsonEncode($data);
}

/**
```

Any solution?

Comment: its a paid extension please contact Mageplaza Support they will help you in better way

Comment: Sure. But support we get on monday.  That's why in the first place l try in my own. Thanks

Comment: Is the issue solved @Sylvester . If solved can you please provide the solution!! It will be useful for me...

Comment: check this please https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/368409/55221